# What does ""the factors that make a given person"" means?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Let me ask you this, when you bring up, you know, the different economic parts of the reason why people have kids, or maybe explain after the fact why they’ve had kids, what do we know generally about the **factors that make a given person** or family more or less likely to have kids.

Can anybody explain after "the factors that make a given person" part and general meaning because I couldn't get the meaning of that sentence? What does "make a given person" mean and how we tie this sentences with "more or less likely to have kids". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is asking what *social*, *economic*, or *other reasons* cause people to have children.

Possibly *make* is incorrectly used in your sentence since usually no one is "forced", *pre se*, to have children (though some religious groups think having large families is an obligation).

The sentence could just as easily been written

> the factors *as to why* a given person or family *are* more or less likely...

Comment: So what does the given exactly means here ?

Comment: "Given" = "*something* particular", "given person" = "any chosen person".  So it means, "any chosen person from our set (possibly random?) of people or families".  "Givens" are "initial conditions" in math proofs.